# How to enlarge my hat?

Tags: support, winter-bash, winter-bash-2016

With this Winter Bash weather, it seems that my hat shrunk by accident!

It's the first time this happened to me.
I have tried to play with it, but did not manage to make my hat grow.

As every research on the subject leads to a paid solution, can someone provide me a free solution?

Comment: *"As every research on the subject leads to a paid solution"* Really? Who is charging for information on Winter Bash hats? (And how do I get in on it?)

Comment: @DragandDrop Is your hat _this_ year intentionally small (as a reference)?

Comment: @wizzwizz4, I knew it! It was a bait.. I knew someone was going to offer me pillz to enlarge it once again!

Answer (score 12):

Just click the 'Show controls' checkbox when applying the hat. This will give you the controls needed to adjust the size and orientation; the hat can be enlarged by moving the dark red circle further away from the hat.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Tirage and move. Are the control displayed. I will. Give it  a try once m home